# Edit simple_form_for with namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, namespaces, simple-form

I'm trying to create a form with Simple Form to edit users profile from admin interface.

- Here are my routes :

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :users
    root 'admin#index'
  end
```

- Admin::UsersController :

```
def edit
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
   end

   def update
     @user = User.find(params[:id])

     if @user.update(user_params)
       redirect_to admin_user_path(@user.id)
     else
       render :edit
     end
   end
```

- And my view :

```
<div class='container mt-4'
   <%= simple_form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
     <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
     <%= f.input :first_name, label: 'Prénom' %>
     <%= f.input :last_name, label: 'Nom' %>
     <%= f.input :description %>
     <%= f.input :email %>
     <%= f.button :submit, 'Enregistrer les modifications', class: 'btn btn-primary rounded' %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

But my form doesn't work, nothing happen when I click the button... What did I miss ?

Comment: Try to change it to: <%= simple_form_for ([:admin, @user]) do |f| %> Also, what errors do you get?

Comment: Pricesely, I have no error...

Comment: When you hit the submit button, copy your terminal log and post it here. Also, try to change it to <%= f.submit %> and see if that helps.

Comment: Nothing in my terminal either, there is only the get action to the form.

Comment: Check the browser console. You can see from the network tab if a request is being sent at all. If not then the issue is most likely caused by some faulty javascript - disable javascript and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the route.

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :users
    root 'admin#index'
    get 'admin#update'
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've finally just modified my view without simple_form syntax and it worked, so I don't know if your solution works...